# Android Google Map Activity recreates after Back Button was pressed

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Google Map in my project, and I created an Activity with the map fragment inside. After map was successfully loaded, if I swipe a little bit and hit Back button quickly (May be when the map is still moving), the Map Activity will reload itself. I tracked its life cycle methods and found that it restarted from OnCreate method. This occurs sometimes, not always.

If I change the launch mode of the activity to "singleTask", it works fine. However, it is not recommended to use singleTask Mode generally, based on [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode).

Can anyone please help to explain what happens under this scene and provide the best way to fix it? Thanks.

The XML of the activity is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.alcatel.movetime.ui.view.map.MapActivity"
    android:clickable="true">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Activity is also pretty simple:

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        final LatLng kidPosition = new LatLng(31.2, 121.5);
        CameraPosition target;
        target = CameraPosition.builder().target(kidPosition).zoom(14).build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(target));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's BaseActivity? How do you start MapActivity. Please be verbose.

Comment: OK, I switched to AppCompatActivity and it has the same issue. The way I start the activity was very normal, just create a new intent with no flags and started it inside another Activity.